# Registration roles

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration

I stumbled on a Problem recently:
I have a Registration Form on my Website which gives the role "Subscriber" by default to everybody who tries to register, but I want a specific E-Mail Domain to get a different role.
I found a [WPSE question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/181771/is-there-a-way-to-set-the-user-role-based-on-email-domain) about this but I don't know where I should insert the PHP Code?
`functions.php` in my Themes folder? I would be really thankful if someone with more knowledge could help me.

I'm using WordPress 5.4.2 with WooCommerce and the Theme Shop-Isle

Comment: You should read them before you add this code inside a Theme - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, add the code in functions.php file of the activated theme.